# Leaflet Image Overlay Show with Pixel Coordinates on map

Tags: image-processing, leaflet, overlay

I have successfully displayed my image on a map at specific location using the bounds of a polygon. Here is the Screenshot of the image displayed on top of map at around specific boundary bounds.

[image]

```
var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(this.imageUrl, this.projectBoundary.getBounds(), {
      opacity: 0.8,
      interactive: true
      }).addTo(this.map);

    var draggableOverlay = new L.Draggable(imageOverlay._image);
      draggableOverlay.enable();
```

I am able to drag it as well and change the location of the image. But what i am trying to achieve is something like in below screenshot, where i can specify specific pixel a coordinate (bounds) values, and then corners would be inside that. Basically, i have two pixel points selected on my image, and now i want to align those point pixel with the bounds of the boundary on the map, just like in the below screenshot, you can see that there are two x icons, one is top left and one is at bottom, they are at specific pixel value of the image.

How can i do that in leaflet image overlay? and then i want to use those two point to resize the image as well on the map. How can i do that in Leaflet ? I haven't been able to find the solution for it.

[image]

This is something that pix4d is doing when you upload image Design, and i want to implement something like that in my application.

I have tried these plugins, but they don't let me provide corners at specific pixel

https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage